# jQuery - Parallax Effect for background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I have a div class that acts as a 'section' on my site. I have given it a background image with the following css:

```
.section-one {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(images/outside-shot-edited.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and would like to apply a parallax effect on it so that when the user scrolls, the image scrolls but at a slower pace.

Is it possible to do this with jQuery for a div using `background-image`?

I don't want anything too complex but just something to add a bit of dynamic movement to the site.

Any suggestions are welcome, I have tried the following but it didn't work...

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.section-one').css('top', -(scrolled * 0.5) + 'px');
}



$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `translate` property

```
function parallax(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.section-one').css({'transform':'translate(0px,'+scrolled /2+'%'});
}



$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

just change the scrolled /2 number to whatever number that suit your need

Answer (score 0):

You can use [parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) which is easy to implement
just add the class parallax-window to your div and the other data parameters

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="/path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
```

Or using jquery

```
$('.parallax-window').parallax({imageSrc: '/path/to/image.jpg'});
```

You can download and find all the parameters and options on [this page](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)